# Why $E[\int_0^t e^{W_t}dW_t] = 0$?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, proof-explanation

I keep reading about one proof I found on internet and I see that they state that $$E[\int_0^t e^{W_s} dW_s] =0 $$

where $W_t$ is Wiener process.

Their justification is the following:

> Note that by definition of the stochastic integral, we have
> $\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^Te^{B_t}dB_t\right]=0$. This follows from the
> fact that the function $f : (t,\omega) \mapsto \exp(B(t,\omega))$
> belong to $H^2[0,T]$ where $H^2$ is the space of progressively
> measurable function such that : \begin{equation} \mathbb{E}\int_0^T
> > f^2(t,\omega)dt < \infty \end{equation}

And I don't quite get why this solve the issue. Could you please explain to me why, or show another, maybe simpler way how it can be proved?

Comment: But the thesis is that $e^W_s$ is a **local** martingale which is not sufficient. It has to be martingale for $E[] = 0$

Comment: I meant $\int_0^t e^{W_s}$ is local martinale

Comment: You are right look at theorem 5 (Ito's isometry) instead : https://almostsuremath.com/2010/03/29/quadratic-variations-and-the-ito-isometry/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a consequence of the basic property of Ito's integral, for any "nice function" $f$, we define that $$\int_0^T f(W_t)\, dW_t$$ to be $\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \sum_{i=0}^n f(W_{t_i})\cdot(W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_i}) $ where $\{t_i\}$ is a equi-distance partition of $[0,T]$. Now use the fact that $f(W_{t_i})$ and $W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_i}$ are independent conditional on $\mathcal{F}_t$ (the natural filtration generated by the Brownian motion at time $t$) and take the expectation. The last sentence should be translated to $$\mathbb{E}[f(W_{t_i})\cdot(W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_i}) \mid \mathcal{F}_t] = f(W_{t_i})\,\mathbb{E}[W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_i}] = 0$$

Comment: Sorry, don't full get how the independence can be used here. Could you please show me how you see this ?

Comment: And additionally could you please also explain why $f(W_{t_i})$ and $W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_i}$ are independent ?

Comment: @Lucian I have edited my answer. Hopefully that makes sense to you now